# What is the ultimate way to set up automated rsync from crontab, to sync content from one linux machine to another over the internet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, rsync

I have picked up a small project that involves a Ubuntu webserver to use Rsync to pick up content (images and a CSV file for importing into the mySQL db), which runs at 10 minute intervals for a smooth update.

It has been working well for a few years, until just recently. As I have my suspicions that what was in place previously was perhaps not the most well set up and secure options, I would appreciate some input from experienced people on how to redo this.

Currently the system which stopped working recently, functioned like this -

On the webserver, this line runs in crontab:

```
*/10 *  * * *   root    /home/a/b/abc/web/rsync.script
```

The contents of the rsync.script file are as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh
# This script updates the website with the latest CSV by RSYNC and imports the CSV into the MySQL database.
# Now also imports the product images from the office server (added 26/10/2011).

# Step 1 - clearing away the previous data
rm /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html/import/csvdata/*

# Step 2 - getting the new CSV and updating the product image directory
rsync -a office.address.here::abc /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html/import

# Step 3 - chown/chmod what we have imported
chown -R 2022:sites /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html/import
chmod -R 744 /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html/import/*
chmod 0755 /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html/import/csvdata
chmod 0755 /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html/import/images

# Step 4 - run the PHP to import the new CSV into the database
cd /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html
php /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html/csv-import.php

exit 0
```

I have identified that the part that has broken, is Section 2 in the above. When attempted to run manually from the webserver command line, the following result occurs:

admin@webserver:/home/a/b/abc/web# sudo rsync -a office.address.here::abc /home/a/b/abc/web/public_html/import
    @ERROR: failed to open lock file
    rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1522) [receiver=3.0.4]

There is no /etc/rsync.conf or /etc/rsyncd.conf file on the webserver. I'm unsure if one was there initially or if it is required, given the method of use in this example.

On the office machine, which is a Debian box, we have the following /etc/rsync.conf file:

```
max connections = 2
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
timeout = 500

[abc]
  comment = ABC RSync
  path = /home/abc/samba_websync/websync/
  read only = no
  list = yes
  uid = abc
  gid = abc
  #auth users = mongrel
  list = yes
  #hosts allow = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/24
  #secrets file = /etc/rsync.secrets
```

It worries me that apparently there is no security in place throughout this communication.

I've spent the day reading a number of howto's and tutorials, and to be honest it is getting a bit more confusing if anything. I am confident I do not want to repair the current system. I want to implement a more secure and better system. The new system needs to:

1 - sync only changes made on the office machine, as there are a LOT of image files for products and we do not want to be transferring those every 10 minutes!
2 - the communication needs to talk seamlessly without the need to input a password manually.

The webserver and the office machine are located some distance away, and are not in any way within a LAN. They communicate over the Internet.

I am open to best, efficient methods to achieve this!

Thank you in advance. :)

I have root access to both machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am withdrawing this question as it is no longer relevant. The original Rsync function was broken by a serious disk issue on the Linux machine that was the supply to the webserver. The webserver is also now quite old and is being replaced with a more up-to-date server from which I will run Unison from as per Bernards recommendations above. This will now sync from a Windows machine in the office.

Thank you to Bernard and Raul for their replies. It's always appreciated to hear from others even if the responses are not exactly what you're looking for initially, as they can often be kept in mind for modifications later on! Bernards response regarding Unison is a perfect example in this case. Thank you.

Cass

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)?

I find it relatively easy to setup and maintain, and offers plenty of useful features.

Unlike Rsync, Unison updates both replicas, but you can make it unidirectional with `-nocreation` and `-noupdate`. 
To use it with crontab, see `-batch` option.

Comment: Hi Bernard, I will look into Unison, however I'd prefer to not need to install additional packages on the webserver if I can help it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is office.address.here listen at TCP 873 port?

rsync can operate remotely via a xinetd attached service, that will require xinetd running and listening on 873, or over ssh, using a remote connection, tipically using TCP port 22.

**rsync** can deal with deleted files and ownership and permissions, so steps 1 and 3 may be unnecessary.
**rsync** will only transfer those files that are changed, and for transfer files across internet, you should use **rsync** over ssh. Use of rsa keys will allow you a non-interactive secure operation.

Look at rsync documentation

Comment: Thanks Raul, are you able to offer a bit more advice on this? I've already looked at the documentation as stated earlier and this has really not helped me at all. It's added more confusion more than anything.